# Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context for XCTAssertEqual

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I see the error `Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context` when I call the test method `XCTAssertEqual`. I've tried explicitly adding `[(Character,Int)]` to `expected` but I still see this error. I'm not sure what else to try.

How can I get the swift compiler to understand?

TEST:

```
func testFrequencyCountOnInput() {
    let huff = Huffman("ANNA")
    let expected: [(Character,Int)] = [("A", 2), ("N", 2)]
    XCTAssertEqual(huff.frequency, expected)
}
```

CODE:

```
class Huffman {
    private(set) var frequency: [(Character, Int)]

    init(_ input: String) {
        self.frequency = Huffman.sortedFrequency(for: input)
    }

    static private func sortedFrequency(for input: String) -> [(Character, Int)] {
        var frequency = [Character: Int]()
        for char in input {
            frequency[char] = (frequency[char] ?? 0) + 1
        }
        let sorted = Array(frequency).sorted(by: {$0.1 > $1.1})
        return sorted
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is a bit misleading: A tuple does not conform to Equatable by default.

Comment: It looks like I can't extend tuples either!

Comment: Avoid tuples outside of a temporary scope.

Comment: I can return a dictionary and sort later, but I wanted to test that the frequency is sorted too.

Comment: did my answer help you?

Comment: Thanks! You both put me on the right path. I've refactored my code so I'm only using a tuple in a temporary scope which means I do not need a custom type for a tuple now, but it was helpful to see how to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think using `Tuple` here is not a good idea. Instead, you can refactor it to some type. For example:

```
struct Frequency: Equatable {
    let char: Character
    let count: Int
}
```

`Struct` is good, it is a value type (as a `Tuple`) and [can automatically synthesize conformance to `Equatable` protocol](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md).

Next step is the `Huffman` class. For such a tiny problem you have a tons of code. Let's try to refactor it too:

```
final class Huffman {
    private(set) var frequency: [Frequency]

    init(_ input: String) {
        frequency = input.counts
            .map { Frequency(char: $0.key, count: $0.value) }
            .sorted(by: { $0.count > $1.count })
    }
}

extension String {
    var counts: [Character: Int] {
        return reduce(into: [:]) { d, c in
            d[c] = d[c, default: 0] + 1
        }
    }
}
```

Note, this code calculates the frequency in `String` extension's `counts` property (maybe not the best name), then `map` result to `[Frequency]` and finally, sorting it's not a big problem. Much less code and more accurate.
And here we go with our single test:

```
func testFrequencyCountOnInput() {
    let huff = Huffman("ANNNA")
    let expected: [Frequency] = [
        Frequency(char: "N", count: 3),
        Frequency(char: "A", count: 2)
    ]
    XCTAssertEqual(huff.frequency, expected)
}
```

All works fine, even the `sort` feature.